# Call Ajax API with jQuery and correct headers

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I call this POST API using javascript or jquery? I'm not sure where to add the login parameters:

**This curl works very well**

`curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'authorization: Token token=some-number-token' -d 'login=number-login&authentication_field=client_token&authentication_value=some-number-value' 'http://myurl/api/login_session'`

And I try it:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://myurl/api/login_session',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
             xhr.setRequestHeader("Authentication", "Token token=some-number-token" + btoa("login&authentication_field=client_token&authentication_value=some-number-value"))
        },
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

**but when I call with Ajax, i'm getting it as unauthorized. I'm forgetting something**

Thank you if you can help me

Comment: `Content-Type` is wrong, and to set multiple headers, you need to call `xhr.setRequestHeader()` multiple times, once for each header. You're also trying to put the request body into the header; you need `data: "login..."` to send the `-d` part.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you, it worked!!